# Direct serial port connectivity from arduino to android for data communication

Tags: android, usb, arduino

Using Arduino I can get the sensor values logged into the serial monitor over the USB cable...
Is there any way that I can read these values directly on an android tablet by connecting a usb convertor(So that I can tramnsmitt it via GPRS to a server Db)...Please give my some solid directions...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it wired if you use a FT232 or CP2102 converter. Here are a couple apps on the Google Play store that act as a serial monitor.

[USB Serial Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oneman.tools)

[Slick USB Serial Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slickdevlabs.apps.usbtoserialterm&hl=en)

One thing to note is that wired USB communication with Android is not very common, so you may run into some problems depending on the phone you are using. If you want a more guaranteed solution, look into an Arduino Bluetooth module that supports SPP - Serial Port Profile. You can connect the Arduino's RX/TX pins to the Bluetooth module, and have it communicate with the Android device over a wireless Bluetooth serial connection.

Also, here is a similar question on SO, however the answer may have outdated information regarding using the wired solution.
[How to make Android and Arduino communicate without a wireless module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140882/how-to-make-android-and-arduino-communicate-without-a-wireless-module)

Comment: **IF** both the hardware and software of the tablet support it.  And beware it may be difficult to keep the tablet powered if doing this for any length of time, unless the tablet charges through something other than the USB connector or is one of the few that have been hacked to charge with custom cabling while operating as USB hosts.